# Chrome loads on win8 boot, and crashes

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome

Nothing changed, but now when win 8 boots, chrome (default browser) launches itself in desktop, tries to go to -

```
go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=219472&clcid=0x409
```

which doesnt seem to be a page, and then Chrome crashes.  I can close it and reload chrome no problem.

There are 3 Intel onboard graphics related programs that load on startup, and nothing else - as in task manager.

What happened.  How do I stop it?

Comment: What did you use to determine [what loads on startup](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx)? Is Chrome set to be your default browser?

Comment: Is there a typo in the url?  An extra 'r' in mircrosoft?

Comment: I edited the post to reflect the questions.  Thanks.  Because chrome crashed I had to manually copy the address and got it wrong

Comment: go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=219472&clcid=0x409 redirects itself to bing.com just change the page that chrome opens to.

Comment: that address not the chrome homepage.  something is launching that url, and if it just goes to bing it shouldnt be crashing chrome.  once it tries the page it crashes so dont get what change the page means...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue resolved after uninstallation of [K9 filter](http://www1.k9webprotection.com/) program.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information.  The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: had problem.  now dont have problem because of this answer.  Now anyone with the same problem will look at the answer and see what program may be causing the problem.  It seems that this program was causing the error.  How is it not an answer?

Comment: No, it's okay to stay as an answer /cc @kin

Comment: @slhck It was not an answer in its original form.